# Big Space between items in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm implementing Comment Page like Facebook. Somehow I'm getting a plenty of white space. Check this out!

[image]

When I scroll it to the bottom... the rest of comments are there.. so weird

[image]

Here is my render function and FlatList

```
render() {
    return (
        <RkAvoidKeyboard style={styles.bigContainer} onResponderRelease={(event) => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}>
        <FlatList
          ref='list'
          style={styles.root}
          data={this.props.comments}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}/>
            {this._renderKeyboard()}
        </RkAvoidKeyboard>
    )
  }

_keyExtractor(item, index) {
    return item.id;
  }

  _renderSeparator() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.separator}/>
    )
  }
```

I set the background color of the FlatList and it colors all screen (except the keyboard and navigation). I didn't notice this until I implement my Keyboard input. So nothing wrong with Keyboard.

This is so werid..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting null for my Avatar Image and that showed huge blank list.

I figured this out while printing all comments on console.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

To me the space looks exactly the size of keyboard, instead of using the RkAvoidKeyboard spacer, try using [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer)

Its easy to set up and you will just have to set it under your comment textInput component or at the bottom of the container whichever suits you.

Here is a sample that I can provide and that may help you

```
<View>

<FlatList
    data = {dataSource}
    renderItem = {({item}) => this._renderFlatListItem(item)}
    keyExtractor = {(item) => item.id}
/>


<View style={style.textInputContainer}>

    <TextInput
        placeholder={"Text goes here"}
        ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({currentMessage:text})}
        value={this.state.message}
        multiline={true}
        underlineColorAndroid = {'transparent'}
    />

    <TouchableHighlight 
        underlayColor={'transparent'} 
        style={style.sendButtonContainer} 
        onPress = {() => {this._sendMessage();}}>

        <Image  source={require('../../Assets/Images/shape.png')} 
                style={style.sendButton} resizeMode="contain"/>

    </TouchableHighlight>


</View>

<KeyboardSpacer/>
```

All the best!

Comment: That's actually GREAT point. Thanks for the contribution. It actually solved my KeyboardSpacer problem but the space remains same. Any more thought?

Comment: Try adding style = {{flex:1}} to the flatList

Comment: Any idea on this post?? I think you may have some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864293/how-to-draw-square-to-tag-an-object-react-native