# How to draw square to tag an object. (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-image

I see many mobile apps having a feature that user can draw a square to indicate something to tag on the image.

I'm building `Face Tagging` app and basically **user draws square on the boundary of human's face on the image**.

I've Googled it many times but I'm not sure RN has some feature library for tagging.

How can I achieve this? Is there any good library to **draw square on image?** And it will be even better if I can remember its coordinate width, height, and position of the rectangle.

Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated!

This is an example below

[image]

Comment: This is sooooo frustrating. Not even a clue

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If then can you kindly post your solution here

Comment: Hi. If you solved the problem then can you post your solution in github and share the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React Native ART library to draw shapes on top of image. It is a standard library that ships with React Native (although not linked to the binary by default).

Regarding the algorithm:

- Render an image
- Overlay image with React Native's `ART.Surface`
- Detect taps to get coordinates + overlay the rest of the image
- Once you have coordinates of the tap, you can draw a shape you want
- Stop drawing shape when user removes his finger (`onPressOut` event)

Where to go from here:

- [Basic tutorial, explaining how to wire up React Native and ART](http://browniefed.com/blog/getting-react-art-running-on-react-native/)
- [Unofficial(there no official one) documentation](https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md)

Comment: React.surface looks great but it looks like too hard to implement it. :( Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You can add children (in your case, square Views) to an Image tag, so you could do something like

```
<Image src={...}>
  <View
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 120
      left: 100,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      borderWidth: 1
    }}
  />
</Image>
```

You can get the x and y coordinates with the PanResponder API instead of hardcoding the top and left style properties

Edit: RN 50=< Removed support of nested content inside , use [ImageBackground](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) instead

Comment: Very Cool. I found very useful library: react-native-gesture-responder

Comment: PanResponder API seems very useful on this project

Comment: Updated link to [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into react-native PanResponder, or react-native-gesture-handler PanGestureHandler. It is a component that responds to touch input, and calculates the x and y values when you drag your finger, it will also tell you the distance travelled from where the finger started.

You can use this data and pass the x and y travel distance back into the width and height value of a View component to make it drag out a box with your finger.

EDIT:

Here's something I just put together as a bit of an experiment using react-native-gesture-handler.

[image]

```js
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { GestureEvent, PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerEventPayload } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const Test = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState<{ x: number; y: number }>(null);
  const [end, setEnd] = useState<{ x: number; y: number }>({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState<{ w: number; h: number }>({ w: 0, h: 0 });

  const onPress = (event: GestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerEventPayload>) => {
    const { x, y, translationX, translationY } = event.nativeEvent;
    if (!start) setStart({ x: y, y: x });
    setDimensions({ w: translationX, h: translationY });
  };

  const onEnd = () => {
    if (!start) return;

    setEnd(start);
    setStart(null);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={onPress} onEnded={onEnd}>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
              top: start?.x ?? end?.x,
              left: start?.y ?? end?.y,
              width: dimensions?.w ?? 0,
              height: dimensions?.h ?? 0,
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Test;
```